# Android view background erase

Tags: android

I am currently developing a single view android app using the simple invalidate/onDraw strategy, and have noticed that the canvas always appears erased prior to the invocation of the onDraw method. Does anyone know of a simple way to preserve the current canvas contents prior to the onDraw method call? Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a bitmap to store the last drawn state and in every `onDraw` method call, draw the bitmap to the canvas before anything else.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but I was hoping to avoid having to update areas of the screen which haven't changed (i.e. by not having the system perform an implicit erase prior to the onDraw call.)